# AsParallel crashing a MonoTouch app

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, task-parallel-library, plinq

MonoTouch [advertises](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/) support for `AsParallel` on its website with this code snippet:

```
from item in items.AsParallel ()
   let result = DoExpensiveWork (item)
   select result;
```

However, even a trivial sample crashes my app:

```
 var items = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
 var twice = (
        from x in items.AsParallel()
        select 2 * x
    ).ToArray();
```

[image: System.ExecutionEngineException has been thrown. Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Linq.Parallel.QueryNodes.WrapHelper:<Wrap<code>1>m__4A<int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator</code>1<int>)' while running with --aot-only.]

I know MonoTouch can't handle virtual generic methods but isn't PLINQ supposed to work?
What is it wrong that I am doing?

MonoTouch version is 5.3.5.

Same goes for `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured ---> System.Exception:
Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel:<ForEach`1>m__36<int> ()' while running with --aot-only.
See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
```

Comment: @James: AFAIK --aot-only is the only mode possible on the real iOS device because JIT is forbidden by Apple.

Comment: This is probably a bug, report here, and attach a quick project to reproduce it: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a known limitation with MonoTouch and generics](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations#Limited_Generics_Support) - in this case it's because you're working with structures.

It should work if you use objects instead:

```
var items = new object [] { 1, 2, 3 };
var twice = (
    from x in items.AsParallel()
    select 2 * x
).ToArray();
```

We're working on fixing some of these limitations, so it would be nice if you could file a bug report with a sample project for us to have a look to see if it is possible to actually fix this case on day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now the structures were to blame.